# Keeping ColorIndex in a variable (VBA/Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, colors, row

I have some code to change the color of an entire row, highlighting it when a cell is chosen. The problem is when I want the row to get back to the anterior color.

```
Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
```

That changes it always to the color 15, but I want to keep the anterior color in a variable to use it here. How do I do it?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
'declare your new variable 
Dim anteriorColor 
'set your new variable 
anteriorColor = Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex
```

Comment: The variable declaration is not a good learning example as it doesn't specify the type. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables says implicitly typed variables (i.e. type not specified) are of type Variant. A user new to VBA may not be able to appreciate the reasons for the behaviour of anteriorColor because its type is unclear. Use `Dim anteriorColor As XXXX` where `XXXX` is the appropriate variable type. (Don't ask me what that is for ColorIndex. :-)